# ODataController Post method "undefined"

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a OData Controller with the Action as :

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("PostUpdate")]
public async Task<string> PostUpdate(HttpRequestMessage eventsToUpdate)
{

 //Do something
}
```

This is how I am calling the controller through the ajax call:

```
var updateDataArray = [];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  //Build the data
  var updatedT = {
   "Id" : (Id)?Id:0,
   "Desc" : CalculatedDesc
   }
   updateDataArray.push(updatedT);
}

Url = "Api/Odata/PostUpdate"

$.ajax({
url :Url,
type:"POST",
data:updateDataArray ,
dataType : 'json',
success : function(result) {

}
});
```

The problem is when the control is in the Action method and when I put 
`eventsToUpdate.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` in immediate window I am getting the output as : `"Undefined :&undefined"`
what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with parameter of `PostUpdate` method. In ajax, to call a method with data you must have to match the parameter name with datatype. First, make a json object named `eventsToUpdate` with type `HttpRequestMessage` and call like this:

```
$.ajax({
url :Url,
type:"POST",
data: eventsToUpdate,
dataType : 'json',
success : function(result) {

}
});
```